# Including additional files when publishing an app with Visual Studio 2012

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2012

I have a console application that I've been developing and I'm just about ready to publish it for consumption.

However, there's a file that the app needs to reference (a couple files actually) and I'd like to try to include these either during install logic or via an outside process. Here's the situation:

The application fires off a load test based on some criteria the user chooses. The load test is defined by a .loadtest file which is created outside of this project.

So what I would like for the installer to do is contain the .loadtest files and just shove them in a default directory that the project can reference.

I can't figure out how to add this specific file as a pre-requisite or anything though, in the publish wizard. Any ideas?

Comment: If you set the .loadtest as a content file, won't VS publish that along with the other files and include it in the main directory or bin directory of your application?

Comment: This is my first full app that needs to be published. Can you explain what you mean by "content file"? You mean just add it as a file within the solution? If that's the case, I'll just publish it and see what it does with that separate file.

Comment: Nope, if I add it just to the Solution it doesn't include it at all.

Comment: Ah-ha, but if I set it to relate to the build as "Content" it will. Sweet. That looks to be the answer.

Comment: Great!  I wasn't 100% sure in your case, thus the comment instead of answer the first time around.  Awesome you have it working!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you add a file to the solution, it does not automatically get attached as part of the build in some cases.  If you right click the file in your solution explorer and select "Properties", change the build action to "Content".  This will ensure that VS includes the file as part of the build/publish and places it in the output directory of the build process.